# How initialize array and pass a pointer it to base constructor from derived?

Tags: c++, initialization

**Rewrote the question completely. Please, read it carefully**

*Single note to not confuse you: Base constructor expects pointer to constants array. It doesn't store a pointer itself, it stores the data!*

I have the following code:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int*);
    // added this to explain why I need inheritance
    virtual void abstractMethod() = 0;
};

Base::Base(const int *array) {
    // just for example
    cout << array[0] << endl;
    cout << array[1] << endl;
    cout << array[2] << endl;
}

class Derived : private Base {
public:
    Derived();
    void abstractMethod();
};

// who will delete? how to initialize?
Derived::Derived(): Base(new int[3]) {
}
```

I want to hide Base(int*) constructor from the user of my Derived class. To do that I need to supply default values to that array.

The problem is that when I use initialization list like this:

```
Derived::Derived(): Base(new int[3]) {
}
```

array is not initialized and Base constructor prints some garbage.
Another problem with this code: who will free that new array?

How to initialize array before it is passed to Base class?
Is it possible at all in C++?

Comment: On C++ lacking super: Nope. What Java does with super, C++ does by chaining constructors in the initializer lists. The difference lies in the model of object construction: C++ guarantees base classes are fully constructed before any of their non-constructor code is called, whereas Java is willing to accept virtual calls before members of derived classes are fully initialized.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161790/initialize-a-const-array-in-a-class-initializer-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came into another solution:

```
class Int3Array {
    int array[3];
public:
    Int3Array(int v1, int v2, int v3) {
        array[0] = v1;
        array[1] = v2;
        array[2] = v3;
    }
    int* getPtr() {
        return array;
    }
};

Derived::Derived(): Base((Int3Array(1,1,1)).getPtr()) {
}
```

What do you think? Is it also bad?

Comment: Bad. You create a temporary object, which gets destroyed at the closing curly brace. As such, the pointer stored in your `Base` object will point to invalid memory.

Comment: @Xeo Base doesn't store the pointer. It copies/uses values of the referenced array.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: you can't (unless you are willing to rely on possible quirks in a particular compiler). For standard compliance, `Base` must be fully constructed before anything else in `Derived` can be safely touched.

Focus instead of what you are trying to achieve. Why must the array be in `Derived`; why do you feel a need to let `Base` initialize? There are probably dozens of safe ways of achieving what you need.

Comment: if the base class constructor is trying to use array values, it is making an assumption that the derived class has an array - which may not be true in a different derived class.

Comment: Ok, array should not be in Derived. All I want is to construct Base class from Derived. I don't want Derived constructor to have an additional parameter.

Comment: @Vanuan: you are putting the cart before the horse. Surely there's some **reason** you want to make `Derived` depend on `Base`? Whatever that reason is, there are better solutions which would actually make sense.

Comment: Yes, there is. Base class is not written by me. I can't change it. I have only the interface. That base class has only one constructor which needs a pointer to array. That array is accessed in the constructor. I want pass the default array values. The reason why I use inheritance instead of aggregation is that the base class is abstract. I need to implement some methods in it.

Comment: @Vanuan: I'd suggest combining aggregation and inheritance. Minimize your derived class, and let the aggregator class own the array, and take care of the initialization. Try to isolate the base and derived classes from the rest of your application (e.g., let your derived class be a private nested class in the aggregator): I'm getting a funny smell from the base class interface!

Answer (score 2):

You can use static function to generate your objects:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int*);
};

class Derived : Base {
public:
    static Derived createDerived()
    {
        int *a= new int[3];
        a[0]=a[1]=a[2]=1;
        return Derived(a);
    }
    ~Derived()
    {
       delete [] array;
    }
private:
    int *array;
    Derived(int * a):arrary(a),Base(a)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's some really bad design. Why would you need a constructor that takes an `int*` in your `Base` class, when there is no member to initialize?
Taken from your comment on Pontus' answer, it seems you are aware of that flaw.

```
class Base {
private:
    int array[3];
public:
    Base(int* arr);
    virtual ~Base();
};

class Derived : Base {
public:
    Derived();
};
```

You would then pass the array back to the base class using initialization lists:

```
Derived() : Base(new int[3]) {
    array[0] = array[1] = array[2] = 1;
}
```

You basically call the constructor of `class Base` and pass the parameter.
And the constructor of `Base` would use an initialization list too:

```
Base(int* arr) : array(arr) {
}
```

Also, when the `Derived` constructor gets executed, the `Base` object is already fully initialized, that is promised by the standard.
Of course, you'd have to handle the destruction of your dynamically allocated array in `Base`:

```
virtual ~Base(){
    delete [] array;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Suppose that I have only public interfaces to Base. It has 1 constructor that takes int array of predefined size. I want to create that array, fill it with some values and pass it to the Base constructor. That's all. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
Derived::Derived(): Base(new int[3]{1,1,1}) {
}
```

But alas, this is valid only in C++0x. g++ gives me a warning:

```
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
```

Comment: `new int[3]{1,1,1}` The curly braces emit that warning. Another possibility is a global function that returns an allocated array and to pass that to the constructor of `Base`.

Comment: Nice! But like the others said, it's bad design. I HIGHLY recommend that you use the Boost Pointer Container vector instead of array, if you're forced to initialize this way.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find at this point is to use a static array:

```
class Derived : private Base {
public:
    Derived();
    void abstractMethod();
    static int array[3];
};

int Derived::array[3] = {5, 5, 5};

Derived::Derived(): Base(array) {
}
```

Feel free to add your comments.

Comment: If you need to have only one instance(singleton), than make it  fully singleton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern, otherwise wrong solution.

Comment: But why is it wrong? I'm just passing a pointer to my const static array. The only thing the Base is doing is printing my array values (see above).

Comment: first add @ and my name to your comments, without it I will not inform about your comments. Is `Derived::array` same for all Derived classes(always {5,5,5})? I don't understand?

Comment: @Ashot Yes, all Derived objects will initilize themselves with the same array. This my design goal. Base is a general class. Derived is a specialization with {5,5,5} values passed to Base constructor.

Comment: then it is Ok( for your NEW question).