# static initializer list for wrapper class

Tags: c++, object-initializers

Is it possible to "pass" somehow a static initializer list at construction time to a container wrapper class that than in turn initializes its member?

```
struct bar {
  bar(void * ptr): ptr(ptr) {}
  void * ptr;
};

template<class T, int N>
struct foo
{
  foo( args ) :store(args)  {}  // here the arg list should be passed

  T store[N];
};

int main()
{
  bar b[2]={NULL,NULL};
  foo<bar,2> f(NULL,NULL); // This should be possible
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot use STL or Boost.

Let me just explain, if you doubt the usefulness of this. First, this is a very "cooked-down" setup. Explaining the whole setup is not adequate to post here nor would it help. Just imagine a case, where you have a nested expression template tree, you traverse it at compile-time and collect the involved objects and store them in a container wrapper like the above. If you have further question please ask.

Edited: The default constructor of T should *not* be called.

Comment: C++0x makes this easy. I'll have a go at a C++98 answer though

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I can't use c++0x.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161790/initialize-a-const-array-in-a-class-initializer-in-c They're talking about a const array there, but it's the same underlying problem

Comment: I take it you can't/won't add a level of indirection by making `store` be an array of pointers?

Comment: “Unfortunately I cannot use STL or Boost.” – why? This sounds moronic. It’s like using C# and being unable to use the `String` class. Or all of the .NET framework, in fact.

Comment: @Konrad - possibly some embedded device? That was my assumption anyway.

Comment: This code piece gets compiled by NIVIDA CUDA Frontend++. There is some support for STL (via thrust) -- but not in kernel code. Thrust tries to make your life easier if you write host code. I am working on a JIT compilation solution for expression templates.

Comment: @Frank That’s a valid reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1: va_args

If you agree to make bar POD this can be done with `va_args`:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

struct bar {
  void * ptr;
};

template<class T, int N>
struct foo
{
  foo(...)  { // here the arg list should be passed
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      store[i] = va_arg(ap, T);
    }
    va_end(ap);
  }

  T store[N];
};

int main()
{
  foo<bar,2> f(bar(),bar());
}
```

It's not great though - you have to trust the caller a little too much for my liking and the POD requirement could be quite limiting.

### Method 2: range

If you agree to make your type `T` both default constructable and assignable you can use this method:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct bar {
  bar(void * ptr): ptr(ptr) {}
  bar() {}
  void * ptr;
};

template<class T, int N>
struct foo
{
  foo(T *begin, const T *end)  { // here the arg list should be passed
    // Normally I'd use std::copy here!
    int i = 0;
    while (begin != end) {
       assert(i < N);
       store[i] = *begin++;
    }
  }

  T store[N];
};

int main()
{
  bar b[2]={NULL,NULL};
  foo<bar,2> f(&b[0], &b[sizeof(b)/sizeof(bar)]);
}
```

It's not quite seamless - you end up with both an array and an instance of your object, but you can make the array `static const` and kept well hidden from the rest of the code at least.

### Method 3: operator overloading tricks

You could also use a trick with `operator,` to reduce all of the items into one parameter, which IIRC is similar to what [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) does.

Comment: Thanks Awoodland! Nice solutions. Unfortunately both have the same problem: The standard constructor of T is called at construction time of the wrapper class. Instead a constructor taking arguments should be called, like in my original code for the first definition of "b".

Comment: I don't think it's possible without either new syntax (C++0x) or copy constructing them/assigning from elsewhere.