# How can an array be initialized in a constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, boolean, initializer-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [initialize a const array in a class initializer in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161790/initialize-a-const-array-in-a-class-initializer-in-c)

If I have a class with a member variable that is an array of bools, how can I initialize the array in the initializer list of the constructor to all false values? Or will they be initialized by default to all false?

```
class example {
public:
  example()
    : // What goes here to initialize _test to 64 false values?
  {
  }

private:
  bool _test[64];
};
```

Comment: [This has already been answered](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161790/initialize-a-const-array-in-a-class-initializer-in-c&sa=U&ei=B6o7T5eAB8Pu0gGE2cjVCw&ved=0CBcQFjAB&sig2=4ZeSnYECc7vy7ngjYj3YOQ&usg=AFQjCNG7PSUZXNuACyocYKjMa75gOtQg1g)

Comment: No, by default they aren't initialized to nothing. Can't you iterate over all elements?

Comment: Why not just a for-loop in the constructor to do it? You could also use memset which is even more efficient.

Comment: @guitarflow :Assigning the elements to 0 inside the for-loop (inside the constructor) is not **initialization**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
class example {
public:
  example()
    : _test()
  {  
  }

private:
  bool _test[64];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
example() :_test()
    : // zero initialization
  {
  }
```

Comment: This works? I guess with bools this would preset the array with false values?

Comment: @guitarflow : The question says "how can I initialize the array in the initializer list of the constructor to all **false** values?"

Comment: Of course, I have just never seen this form before. Can you also use that to initialize it to some other int value or true in case of bool?

Comment: @guitarflow : No we can only use this to zero (value initialize in case of non PODs) initialize the elements.