# How do I initialize an array within a class without using C++11 Features?

Tags: c++, c++11

How do I initialize an array within a class in c++ without using Initialization Lists (which I think is a c++11 feature)? My compiler (VS2013) does not support c++ 11 to its full extent, sadly.

Comment: this thread seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161790/initialize-a-const-array-in-a-class-initializer-in-c

Comment: You can only initialize non-static data members (inside a class) in C++11.

Comment: `std::array` is supported by VS2013.

Comment: Do you need to initialize the array differently than zero initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 supports `Initializer lists`, this means you can easily do :

```
--C++11: default initialization using {}
int n{};      --zero initialization: n is initialized to 0
int *p{};     --initialized to nullptr
double d{};   --initialized to 0.0
char s[12]{}; --all 12 chars are initialized to '\0'
string s{};   --same as: string s;
char *p=new char [5]{}; 
vector<int> vi {1,2,3,4,5,6};
vector<double> vd {0.5, 1.33, 2.66}; 
etc
```

Or other forms which are supported in C++11.
if you are not fond of it you can also use the older methods such as :

You can simply do as follows:

```
int bar [5] = { 10, 20, 30 };
```

Which creates an array like this:

```
---------------------------------
|  10  |  20  |  30  |  0  |  0  |
---------------------------------
```

You can also have :

```
int baz [5] = { };
```

which translates to :

```
-------------------------------
|  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
-------------------------------
```

or you might have :

```
int foo [] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12 };
```

which translates to :

```
----------------------------------
|  16  |  2  |  77  |  40  |  12  |
----------------------------------
```

If you are dealing with classes and their objects you can simply call your constructor like this:

```
Point aPoint[3] = {
   Point( 3, 3 ),
   Point( 13, 6 ),
   Point( 32, 98 )
};
```

All the former rules apply to this form as well. 
If you declare an static array, they will be initialized based on their types default (e.g int defaults to 0 and etc)